# how to use font family enzo in a web page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, font-family

how to use font family enzo in a  web page the source  is given below.. 
please help to solve the problem..already tried code is attached with this

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: Enzo;
        src: url('fonts/EnzoOT-Medi.otf');
    } 
    @font-face {
        font-family: Enzo;
        font-weight: bold;
        src: url('fonts/EnzoOT-Bold.otf');
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please read the [How to Ask FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you only specify, that `font-face` has value `Enco` too. Now apply that font to elements:

```
p {
    font-family: "Enzo", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) convert your .ttf file [HERE](http://www.font2web.com/)

2) Use this in your Css

```
 @font-face {
      font-family:'EnzoOT-Medi';
      src:url('../font/EnzoOT-Medi.eot');
      src:url('../font/EnzoOT-Medi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../font/EnzoOT-Medi.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../font/EnzoOT-Medi.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
```

3) Add `font-family` to elements or whole body depending on your html code

```
html, body {
        font-family: "EnzoOT-Medi";
    }
```